# Python, Inconsistent zip file extraction

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to extract zip files using the `zipfile` module's `extractall` method.
My code snippet is

```
import zipfile
file_path = '/something/airway.zip'
dir_path = 'something/'
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(dir_path)
```

I have two zip files named, *test* (1.1 mb) and *airway* (520 mb).
For *test.zip* the folder contains all the files but for *airway.zip*, it creates another folder inside my target folder named *Airway*, and then extracts all the files there. Even after renaming the airway.zip to any garbage name, the result was same.

Is there some workaround to get only the files extracted in my target folder? It is critical for me as I'm doing this extraction automated from django

Python version: 3.9.6;
Django version: 2.2

Comment: Just to be clear: Does the ``airway`` file actually contain *a directory* ``Airway`` in which the files are? Zip files are not necessarily flat.

Comment: There is no directory "Airway" inside the zip. I checked the normal extraction. I'm using mac

Comment: Please try and provide a [MRE] in this case.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I found that this information is encoded in the meta-data of [zip archive](https://pymotw.com/2/zipfile/) In test.zip, filenames are a.xml etc. while in airway.zip they are like Airway/a.xml I am searching for some way to edit this data. if you get something, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it seems to be only a problem of the zipfile itself. If you create a zipfile by selecting only the elements you get the result you got with test.zip. If you create it by selecting a folder holding the elements the folder will be there if you extract it again, no matter what you name your zip file.

Answer (score -1):

I have two articles related to this:

- https://www.kite.com/python/docs/zipfile.ZipFile.extractall
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-zip-files-python/

Even if both of these articles do not solve your problem then I think that instead of **zipping the files** in the folder you just zipped the **folder itself** so try by zipping the files inside the folder.